# mouse hover and HTML Area Element

Tags: html, angular

I'm trying to build a map with areas and when the mouse hover over a certain area i want to change the map image to a different map image where this certain area is highlighted using the `onmouseover="changeBgImage"` function I took this code from a code sharing web and it doesn't work
the "mapa" is the main map and the "galil" is the map that I want to change to
(The "mapa" is in the scss)

```
   <div id="mapa" >
 <img src='assets/map/map-reka.png' usemap="#tiulim-map" border="0" alt="">

                    <map name="tiulim-map">
                         <area id="galil" target="" alt="גליל" title="גליל" href="/noar/tiulim/tracks/upper-galilee-area/Pages/upper-galilee-main.aspx" coords="178,103,173,94,175,87,177,78,179,71,180,63,180,55,188,55,196,56,200,59,204,55,212,56,216,51,224,53,226,58,230,64,236,64,243,62,247,58,252,56,258,57,262,61,261,52,264,48,266,41,268,35,269,26,269,16,276,9,278,18,278,26,276,33,276,40,276,48,274,56,274,63,274,72,272,80,269,88,269,95,270,102,258,100,248,98,236,97,226,99,214,102,202,100,191,101" shape="poly" 
  onmouseover="changeBgImage('assets/map/galil.png', 'mapa')" onmouseout="changeBgImage('assets/map/mapa.png', 'mapa')">
```

The "mapa" code in the scss:

```
#mapa{
    background-image: url(C:\Users\פניני\TRIP4U\נוכחי\TRIP4U\src\assets/map/mapa.png);
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            width: 344px;
            height: 927px;

}
```

The browser gives me the following error massage:

```
(index):13 Uncaught ReferenceError: changeBgImage is not defined
    at HTMLAreaElement.onmouseover
```

Comment: Where is changeBgImage function is defined?

Comment: in the export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your event binding.

Try:
`(mouseover)="changeBgImage('assets/map/galil.png', 'mapa')"`

Same goes for the `onmouseout` event.

See: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#target-event

Comment: you might want to use `(mouseenter)` / `(mouseleave)` to only set the background image once, not on every position change of the mouse